# Using this() in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, this

In the online Java tutorials provided by Oracle, I saw the following.

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }
    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    ...
}
```

The first two contructors use the `this()` function to set the class's instance variables. **Is there a reason that the third constructor does not simply utilize `this(x,y,width,height)`.** 
Note: Is this simply to show (in a tutorial setting) that  `this` is also a keyword and can also be used to set instance variables?

Comment: `this()` is not a keyword to set instance variables, it is used to call other constructors of the current object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a reason that the **third constructor** does not simply utilize
>   this(x,y,width,height).

Because **it** is the constructor that would be invoked with

```
this(x, y, width, height);
```

and that would cause an infinite recursive loop.

---

As [Keppil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003634/using-this-in-constructor/23003648#comment35134762_23003634) said in the comments, `this` is a keyword. When used like

```
this(x, y, width, height);
```

in a constructor, it invokes the class constructor with the appropriate parameter list. In this case, that constructor *is* the third constructor. So what you are suggesting is that the third constructor invoke the third constructor which invokes the third constructor, ad nauseam.